# google map V-3 simple problem with latlng

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i was using v2 of google maps. Now i shifted to v3.

In version 2, this WAS working

```
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) { 
        myLatitude = latlng.lat(); 
        myLongitude = latlng.lng(); 
        alert(myLatitude + '  data  ' + myLongitude); 
    });
```

what should be the equvalant of this code in v3 ?? 
i searched a lot, but couldn't find any good result..

I have tried this..

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay , latlng) { 
        myLatitude = latlng.lat(); 
        //myLongitude = latlng.lng(); 
        alert('hi! ' + myLatitude); 
    });
```

but no results..

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docs:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Map

You'll see that the 'click' event passes a [MouseEvent](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MouseEvent) argument, which has a property latLng, so your method signature above is wrong, this should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) { 
    myLatitude = e.latLng.lat(); 
    alert('hi! ' + myLatitude); 
});
```